C# Functional Test Automation via CI/CD
I have a C#.NET-based solution for a console application, which includes two projects: "hotel" and "library." The "hotel" project initiates execution and utilizes services from the "library" project, which uses MSSQL as its database. These are deployed on a VM, where both "hotel" and "library" are part of a single Docker container. This container relies on a SQL Server container for database operations and an export container for pushing SQL data to the cloud. The export container is a separate project developed by another team and reads data directly from the common SQL database. There is no interdependency between the export container and the "hotel" project.
I need to develop functional tests for end-to-end testing, which will be part of a Jenkins CI/CD pipeline. I don't have much experience with Docker or Jenkins, but here is what I have learned so far:

Using Jenkins stages, first, I need to create a Docker container for SQL Server.
After that, I build and run my functional test cases, using the SQL Server Docker container to connect to the database.
I am unsure how to utilize the export container to move data from the SQL Server Docker container to the cloud.

How shall I proceed?

How about setting up an SQL server container by creating and running a Docker container for SQL Server?
You can also build your "hotel" and "library" projects, and execute functional tests connected to the SQL Server container. Or run the export container to transfer data from the SQL Server container to the cloud.
